# Plugin with AJAX on subdomains causes 404 in console

Tags: plugins, ajax, 404-error, subdomains, network-admin

I'm in the beginning of creating a Wordpress plugin. I've done several of these.

I'm using Wordpress 4.6.1 and bbPress 2.5.10 on Plesk 12.5.30.

It is a network installation with a main domain and three subdomains.

Everything works fine on the main domain and mostly fine on the subdomains. No problems on the user side or the admin side.

My plugin does little other than create a button and change it's HTML using AJAX. Very simple so far, but it has a big problem. When loading the dashboard on subdomain sites, the browser console shows:

- GET
  http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/admin/css/admin.css?ver=2.5.10-6063
- JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
- GET
  http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/ivevents/ivevents.js?ver=0.0
  404 (Not Found)

Ignoring the JQMIGRATE line, the two referenced URLs both exist on the server in the right places. No other plugins, and I have many installed, have this problem. Some of them are my own plugins using the same basic strategy.

The AJAX doesn't work on subdomains because it can't find the .js file.

Comment: What is the ievents plugin? Have you contacted ievents support? Is the URL meant to have 2 ievents/ievents/? Also I'm not sure what this has to do with AJAX, there are no AJAX calls, endpoint or code in your question

Comment: If ievents plugin is yours, verify the path, you have two following ievents (as folder) before the filename.

Comment: Having /ivevents/ivevents/ in the URL was a mistake in typing it out. Sorry. I've corrected the question. Problem still exists.

Comment: The AJAX is undeveloped, a simple SQL call, but it never happens because of the error that it can't find the js. Also, there is a jQuery selector click function that never fires for the same reason. Also, in the source for the window, near the error is the following:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://disabilityreviews.org/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/js/tourTip.js?ver=6.2.3'></script>`

I checked, checked, and checked. My ivevents.js file is in the right place. The Wordfence and all other references like it are fine. Only bbpress and my plugin have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now. The file, ivevents.js, has an error in it. Rather than the console identifying the error, it gives the 404 error, as if the file doesn't exist. When I corrected the error in the js file, the console error goes away.

Now, if I could only figure out how to use the console to see errors in .js instead of a 404.

Thanks for the help.